# What does "analytic property" mean?

Tags: analysis, terminology

In the section about the completeness property of the reals of the book *Real Analysis for the Undergraduate* by Mathew A.Pons, the author wrote:

> The final idea necessary to define the real numbers is an analytic property.

I don't know what it means by "analytic property" here? However, I know that an *analytic solution* is an exact solution in contrast with a *numerical solution* (approximate and may not be exact). My guess is that *analytic property* seems to relate to *completeness* (or *continuity*) rather than the *exactness*.

So, is there any generally agreed-upon definition for this term?

Comment: Everything interesting that happens in analysis is because of this last property. Hence properties that somehow have to do with completeness or what happens in some kind of limit over a continuum are often called analytic properties.

Comment: I think he means something other than an algebraic property.  The properties "ordered field" are all algebraic ... operations on 2 elements, relations of 2 elements.  But the "completeness" property is not of that kind.  It must talk about infinite relations or infinite operations or infinite sets.

Comment: The rationals are an ordered field but are insufficient to do analysis since it is not complete. Thus all the analytic properties are related to the completeness property and is also why we can do analysis in other complete spaces like $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins, I'm interested in seeing references to what you mentioned in the comment above. Could you provide me some?

Comment: The term is not being used in a rigorous or technical sense.  It is being used in the same sense as "I am taking a class in analysis".  I don't have this text, so I don't know what property is being described, but presumably it is the completeness property---this is what makes analysis tick, and what distinguishes it from, say, algebra.  A "generally agreed-upon definition" seems unlikely (and not the intention of the phrase in the first place).

Comment: There are `analytic functions`. But `analytic property` is uncommon for me. Did you read the glossary of terms in the back of the book? Some authors give unique definitions to phrases they use or compose. I researched quickly and `analytic property` does not yield many results, which leads me to believe that the author may have created it. Check the back of the book and let us know if `analytic property` appears.

Comment: @FullArray Definition for the term isn't provided anywhere in the book, the book doesn't have *glossary of terms* section as you mentioned. All comments above seem to suggest that this is not a rigorously defined term in maths.

Comment: @TranKhanh some authors engage in that practice, but without a definitive input from the author we cannot conclusively say that the term is fabricated and only the author know what it means.

Comment: "Analytic property" is not a technical term here.  It will not appear in a glossary. It just means a property that has to do with analysis rather than algebra.

Comment: algebra is the mathematics of exact equalities and finitary operations. analysis is the mathematics of approximations, trends, and infinitary operations like limits. The distributive law is an algebraic property of the real numbers, while the completeness axiom is an analytic property.